# When exporting an imported csv, it includes the headers but not the information under the headers

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I have code to import a csv from a path, then I want the code to turn the csv into an excel, with the excel only containing certain headers. I found though in the excel, it will have the headers but none of the information under the headers. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $path
$csv | Export-Csv -Path "Y:\Client Case Files\$company\$incidentfolder\signinlogs.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# sort and filter information for xlsx
$excel = $csv | Select-Object createdDateTime,UserDisplayName,UserPrincipleName,IpAddress,AppDisplayName,ClientAppUsed,IsInteractive,RiskDetail,RiskLevelAggregated,RiskState 
$excel | Export-Excel -Path "Y:\Client Case Files\$company\$incidentfolder\signinlogs.xlsx"
```

Comment: What you're doing is correct. What version of ImportExcel are you using?

Comment: not sure how do i check

Comment: use `(Get-Module importexcel).Version`

Comment: `Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
7      5      2      -1`

Comment: We can't see the csv file you are importing in the first line. Does that actually have those headers? If not, or if they are different to what you select, there will indeed only be hraders as they don't map to any of the fields

Comment: I cant show the actual file, but yes it has headers such as createdDateTime,UserDisplayName,UserPrincipleName,IpAddress,AppDisplayName,ClientAppUsed,IsInteractive,RiskDetail,RiskLevelAggregated,RiskState. And when its imported as csv and exported as excel, the headers are exported but nothing under those headers

Comment: Then, did you check if the input csv file indeed uses the _comma_ as field delimiter? If that is a different character you should let the Import-Csv know using parameter `-Delimiter`, otherwise the file doesn't get parsed correctly

Comment: How do I find out what the delimiter is?

Comment: Just open it in notepad and you can see. BTW, if you want to address someone in a comment type `@` followed by that username so he/she will get notified

Comment: @Theo ahhh thank you, I opened it in note pad and its separated with commas, I tried -Delimiter "," and then ran `$excel = $csv | Select-Object createdDateTime,UserDisplayName,UserPrincipleName,IpAddress,AppDisplayName,ClientAppUsed,IsInteractive,RiskDetail,RiskLevelAggregated,RiskState `  and it still did the thing where it pulls those listed headers but no info under them, this makes no sense

Comment: ok, then just to test. Comment out the last line an instead just type `$excel`. That should show the data on screen. Is there data? If so, your ImportExcel module may be corrupted and you might try to reinstall that.

Comment: @Theo yea this is what I get 
`createdDateTime     : 
UserDisplayName     : 
UserPrincipleName   : 
IpAddress           : 
AppDisplayName      : 
ClientAppUsed       : 
IsInteractive       : 
RiskDetail          : 
RiskLevelAggregated : 
RiskState           : 

createdDateTime     : 
UserDisplayName     : 
UserPrincipleName   : 
IpAddress           : 
AppDisplayName      : 
ClientAppUsed       : 
IsInteractive       : 
RiskDetail          : 
RiskLevelAggregated : 
RiskState           : 

createdDateTime     : 
UserDisplayName     : 
UserPrincipleName   : 
IpAddress :`

Comment: That proves the import csv is incorrect, either wrong delimiter or different field names. Try just `Import-Csv -Path $path` and see what you get on screen

Comment: @Theo I figured it out, I had those objects set for when powershell downloaded sign in logs from azure, I just realized for some reason when you manually download the same logs, there are very small differences in the header names so the header names are different. I wish it just output an error saying it cant select object as those headers didnt exist or something but oh well. Thank you for the help though

Comment: No, Select-Object either selects properties with that exact (altough case-insensitive) name OR simply creates a new empty property with the name you specify. No error messages, that's how the cmdlet works

Answer (score 0):

Check is $excel variable have the data required ?
if not probably your csv file dat headers have extra space at end or start.
try testing below

```
$excel = $csv | Select-Object * 
$excel | Export-Excel -Path "Y:\Client Case Files\$company\$incidentfolder\signinlogs.xlsx"
```

If that also not giving the data probably issue with your excel module